# parse push notification with php

Tags: php, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to push notification with below code

the json I want to get is something like this

```
{
"data": {
    "message": "Hello! Welcome to parse notifications.",
    "title": "AndroidHive"
},
"is_background": false
}
```

below is php code

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$APPLICATION_ID = "T7G0qlJG5ygBVHZFVrqf8VO17vhQeeG3TnshxfQy";
$REST_API_KEY = "ywsoZIXPlrapASLHu5kvNBdCl7kfPe43OW3ugyZd";
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$data = array(
  'channles'=>'',
  'data'=>array('data'=>array(
      'message'=>'Hello! Welcome to parse notifications.',
      'title'=> 'ParseTest',
    ),
    "is_background"=> false
  ),
);
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

But nothing send to my device, anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: BTW: Shouldn't `'channles'=>'',` be `'channels'=>'',`?

Comment: After I change it, it still don't work.

Comment: What's the return value of `curl_exec($curl);`? If it returns `false`, you have to check `curl_error($curl)`.

Comment: I try it, but it don't return anything.

Comment: with curl_error I get `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: I solve it ,thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest changing your API secret after posting it publicly here.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the curl,add such code with make the curl work fine.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  ,false);
```